# MySQL - set dynamic default value

Tags: php, mysql, database, default, default-value

I have table of users in my MySQL database. Is it possible to set default value of column `profile_url` to value of column `Id` ?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Please consider making an [edit] to give more details.

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? Is the column `ID` auto increment ?

Comment: I think in MySQL 8 you can do some things with other column values, have a read of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-types-defaults-explicit for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`trigger`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) to implement the feature. For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER defaultUrl
BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.profile_url = IFNULL(NEW.profile_url, NEW.id);
```

The expression creates a trigger named `defaultUrl` that activates before each row inserted into `MyTable`. If `defaultUrl` is `NULL`, the `id` value is used.

Comment: Thanks for help, it seems it should work, but i have 1 more problem with it. Can i somehow use it if the ID column is autoincrement? When I use any other column it works, but when I want to use value of ID it changes the value to '0' everytime

Comment: @JosefKotoun , I'm not sure, but you could try to use `AFTER` value for trigger time instead of `BEFORE`. Or use autoincrement value from `information_schema` database.