# Get sum of specific columns in row and update in field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Have the table like this

```
Sr.No   Name    Subject1    Subject2    Subject3    Total Marks
1       A         25         65           30           ?    
2       B         52         54           65           ?
3       C        60          54           45           ?
```

I want to make sum of all three subject and like

```
Subject1+Subject2+Subject3= ?
```

And store it in (Total Marks) field separately

How to do with PHP code.

Comment: Have you tried anything? How do you do the insert? Why store the sum? You could just use SQL `sum()`.

Comment: @user3783243 Isn't `SUM()` a group function in SQL? So it will return the sum of the column for all selected or grouped rows! That's not what should be done here.

Comment: Maybe you could just create a new view with this "column"!

Comment: Note that a database table is not a spreadsheet. Fix your schema.

Comment: @ user3783243 sum is an aggregate function. It works on the rows.

Comment: @TechNil show what you have tried so that we can suggest you what to fix or we could get the issue.

Comment: @csabinho Yes, you are right. Math could be used in the query `select (Subject1 + Subject2) as sum`.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the best method is to add a computed column:

```
alter table likethis add column totalmarks int
   generated always as (Subject1 + Subject2 + Subject3);
```

Then `TotalMarks` is always up-to-date.

If the column always exists, you can use `update`:

```
update likethis
    set totalmarks = Subject1 + Subject2 + Subject3;
```

*I do not recommend this approach.*  The value is not recalculated when the data changes.

I don't know what you mean by "How to do with PHP code."  Your question is about modifying tables, so you have to use the database.  You can call the commands from PHP, but that is just the interface to where the real work is happening.

Comment: Hmmm, I've never seen the `generated always`. I'd seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384429/mysql-set-field-default-value-to-other-column and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250756/mysql-set-dynamic-default-value and as such have used triggers. Looking at the manual it appears this functionality has existed for a bit (5.5+), is there a reason you are aware of why none of the others answers recommended this approach?

Comment: Just create a view with the old table and `(Subject1+Subject2+Subject3) AS totalmarks`.

Comment: @user3783243 . . . You have to ask the people who answered why they are not using appropriate features in the database.

Comment: Figured it out. The feature actually is newish, came out in 5.7, not 5.5.